# ошибка Server Error (500) при отправке email

Tags: django, ubuntu, smtp, digitalocean

сервер на digitalocean. 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64

Настраивал всё по туториалу http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

всё стоит всё работает. однако при отправке почты через smtp.gmail.com выдаёт ошибку Server Error (500)

настройки в файле setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secret'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

если запускать с локальной машини 127.0.0.1:8000 всё отправляется корректно. а на удалённом нет.

так же смотрел результат команды

```
result from command netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
->>>>>>result
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 20380/nginx: master
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2702/systemd-resolv
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 957/sshd
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 957/sshd
```

и пробовал открыть порт 587

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <myIPdroplet> –dport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

ошибка в логе

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "http://ip/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
```

прошу помочь Вас, так как уже перерыл всё что только можно

UPD!
при чтении лог файла gunicorn_supervisor.log ошибок нет. Пишет только данные когда перезапускается супервайзер и когда отправляется форма сабмит,  print формы тоже выводится в лог , однако ошибки нету.

так же есть нюанс что базу постгреса не поставил, может ли это быть из-за этого ?

Comment: Если вы запускаете django через gunicorn, значит настраивайте в нём вывод логов и читайте логи — в них всегда обязательно указывается причина ошибки 500

Comment: я открываю через nano  nginx-error.log и там пусто . 
что то делаю не так?

Comment: Непонятно зачем читаете логи nginx, а ошибка-то происходит в django и читать надо логи django. Ещё раз, настраивайте вывод логов в gunicorn

Comment: так как ошибка в django. если налокальном те же скрипты работают. всё что менял это значение ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: «так как ошибка в django» — вот это вы и выясните, как, путём чтения логов.

Comment: «ошибка в логе» — вы всё ещё читаете не те логи. Ещё раз, настраивайте вывод логов в gunicorn и читайте в нём логи

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как это настроить. думал это уже сделано.

Comment: В туториале по ссылке настраивается вывод логов gunicorn через supervisor в файл `/webapps/hello_django/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log`; если вы повторяли всё за туториалом — вот этот файл и читайте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102889/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-andreymal).